# How to get currently opened class in eclipse editor correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the following code, which actually works well:

```
IJavaElement je = null;
IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
if (part instanceof ContentOutline)
    part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    if (part instanceof IViewPartInputProvider)
    {
        Object elem = ((IViewPartInputProvider)part).getViewPartInput();
        if (elem instanceof IJavaElement)
            je = (IJavaElement)elem;
    }
```

But I get a warning:

`Discouraged access: The type IViewPartInputProvider is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.9.1.v20130820-1427.jar`

Seems that this is a dirty way because of accessing internal API. Is there a better way to do this?

**update**

I found out that this code works fine too but doesn't produce any warnings:

```
IJavaElement je = null;
IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
if (part instanceof ContentOutline)
    part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
je = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(((IEditorPart)part).getEditorInput());
```

Since I omitted some checks I'm worried that this code could cause runtime errors if somebody using my plugin has a different eclipse configuration. Any suggestion for improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActivePart()` and `getActiveEditor()` might return null, so might `getActiveWorkbenchWindow()`, and `getActivePage()` (but these are less likely).

You must test `part` to see if it is an `IEditorPart`, The `IWorkbenchPart` returned by `getActivePart()` might be an `IViewPart`.

`JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement()` will only work if one of the Java editors is the active editor. For the many other types of editor that might be active it will return null.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll fix my code next week.

By the way: could you recommend me a book or another source on this topic?

Comment: Sorry but I've being doing Eclipse development so long it is ages since I looked at books for 3.x development.